# Illness and injury

Tags: meaning

I've just heard on BBC Radio 4:

> A man is seriously ill after having been hit by a police car.

Is this a correct use of *ill* (assuming that he hasn't contracted an infection)? I'd not have used *ill* of an injury, however serious.

Comment: I would agree.  Illness exists at the biological level (microbe, virus, gland, body chemistry, etc). You're not ill, but injured, when you cut off your big toe with the lawn mower, etc.

Comment: Unless further information was offered, we cannot know if the term was used correctly or not. Could be that the person seriously injured has a [ruptured spleen](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/ruptured-spleen/basics/symptoms/con-20029359) for all we know.

Comment: Free of a broader context, I would under that the man was possibly in severe trauma and not necessarily injured. This is possible is certain accidents. On the other hand, illness does not have to be due to an infection or disease -- even injuries lead to illness.

Comment: Based on US usage, using "ill" was a stretch, though probably not technically incorrect.  (I would perhaps said "was in serious conditions", though one would have to read the source report to see if that's correct.)  However, remember that this was radio and likely there was some degree of improvisation, if not by the announcer himself then by some writer who had about 30 seconds to "translate" the story from wire reports, etc.

Comment: In serious condition, singular.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Please note that your American reference calls a ruptured spleen an injury, not an illness. :) As noted elsewhere, in AmE, injuries are not illnesses, though illnesses may lead to injuries and vice versa. Severe trauma is an injury (in the US) but being in serious condition is not in any way limited to injury.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, the choice of words makes a difference here.

I would use injury to refer to a laceration or a contusion, anything that happens rather suddenly.

The word "ill" feels like a better fit when talking about a condition of pain and suffering that lasts. The speaker wanted to express that the man is having severe health problems as a **consequence** of the accident. "Injury" would be a good word to describe the trauma at the time of the accident. "ill" however feels like the proper word to describe the condition he is in after the accident.

The speaker could've said:

> A man is seriously ill after having been injured by a police car.

He got hit by a car ->  he was injured -> he lost a lot of blood -> now he's in the hospital, seriously ill.

Even though he's obviously still *injured* as well, the state he now is in is better described as being *ill*. His condition has simply gotten worse over time, either as a direct consequence of his injury or for reasons not (e.g. an infection) or only partially (blood loss following the injury) related to the actual accident. To convey that this development occurred and isn't necessarily directly related to his injury during the accident, the speaker chose to say that he's *seriously ill*.

Maybe that helps clarify it for you.

You stated that you wouldn't say "ill of an injury". I think what the speaker meant in this case was "ill due to the consequences of an injury".

Comment: Very clear and accurate.

Comment: Seems obvious to me, but I speak American.

Comment: @CarSmack Well I'm German so I can relate to being uncertain about the contextual meaning of English words, even commonly used ones. In addition to that I figured there's no harm in providing _too much_ information, so why not go for it.

Comment: @J_LV..+1 great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This is webster's definition of ill

> 1 a chiefly Scottish :immoral, vicious b :resulting from, accompanied
>   by, or indicative of an evil or malevolent intention  c
>   :attributing evil or an objectionable quality  2 a :causing suffering or distress  b
>   comparative also ill·er superlative also illest (1) :not normal or
>   sound  (2) :not in good health; also :nauseated

I would think they meant 'suffering or distress'

I personally wouldn't have used ill, but hey, it's BBC; I guess they know what they're doing

Comment: OED's definition concurs with this: *Of health or bodily condition: Unsound, disordered. Hence, of persons (formerly, also, of parts of the body): Out of health, sick, indisposed, not well; almost always used predicatively.*

Comment: Note that you can't simply reproduce `< >` in answers: you need to substitute the HTML entities `&lt; &gt;`. `< >` produces an XHTML tag, which browsers ignore.

Comment: BBC is a ***British*** Broadcasting Corporation, so you should not be using an ***American*** dictionary to check their language.

Comment: You cannot just drop the word **causing** from the definition. That part describes _ill_ as something that _causes_ distress or suffering. Think along the lines of _an ill omen_. I _hardly_ think the BBC meant the man has turned into a cause of much stress and suffering because he was hit by a car!

Comment: @PeterShor: as long as the _American_ dictionary starts off with a mainly _Scottish_ use of the lemma, it _might_ still shed some light on _British_ usage, even by an _English_ presenter. But in _any_ dictionary, superfluous verbs are rare, so leaving them out of a definition doesn't seem to be a good idea, wherever your dictionary was edited :)

Comment: It is unusual usage of the term 'ill', both by the BBC and in the UK generally. It would, as someone suggested, be more common to say the person was in a 'serious condition', or 'seriously injured'.

Answer (score 2):

Another example of us damn Colonists destroying the King's English.  In the US, "injured" is usually blunt-force trauma, "sick" is a result of disease, and "ill" is almost always going to include some vomiting.

US Dept. of Labor uses the term "injury" to describe obvious "cause and effect" damage, and "illness" as something  where the cause is not immediately apparent.

Comment: That's a useful comment. May not count for an answer.

Comment: As I implied in another comment, in the UK we would normally not use 'ill' in this context. I don't believe there is any significant difference in the way these things are described in the UK versus North America.